# Event Receiver CancelWithRedirectUrl issue with multiple selected list items

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, event-handlers

I've got my event receiver (`ItemDeleting`) working almost exactly the way I'd like it to.

Upon certain conditions in the `ItemDeleting` event, I am setting the status to `CancelWithRedirectUrl` and setting the redirect URL like so:

```
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/AppPage.aspx";
```

The only problem I'm experiencing now is that if a user selects and deletes *more than 1 item* at a time. The event receiver apparently tries to redirect twice and I get an error stating the following (twice as you see):

> ```
> The server has encountered the following error(s):
> The request was redirected to ...
>
> The server has encountered the following error(s):
> The request was redirected to ...
> ```

If I debug I can see my event receiver is actually executing twice. Is there some graceful way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain this will work but I believe that if you disable event firing it does so for the EventReceiver. Try wrapping your code in a disable event firing scope.

http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/
Using this class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Disabled item events scope
/// </summary>
/// <see cref="http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/disable-item-events-firing-during-item-update/"/>
class DisabledItemEventsScope : SPItemEventReceiver, IDisposable
{
    bool oldValue;

    public DisabledItemEventsScope()
    {
        this.oldValue = base.EventFiringEnabled;
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        base.EventFiringEnabled = oldValue;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And call it like this:

```
using (DisabledItemEventsScope scope = new DisabledItemEventsScope())
{
    //Redirect and any other code.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I am using a similar approach to your recommendation in other areas of the application and it works great.  I don't think it would be helpful in this case because the events are being fired due to user action and not being fired by a server-side call to item.Update().  If I can't come up with a clean way to handle multiple items, I am considering client side preventative measures like:  a) Preventing users from being able to check more than 1 list item checkbox at a time.  b) Disabling the "Delete Item" action if more than 1 list item is checked.

Answer (score 0):

`EventFiringEnabled` is not the answer as it prevents firing new events as the result of updates done by my code.

The cause of the error is that `ItemDeleting` event is synchronous. It means that its receivers are executed in the same thread as original operation and moreover all other sync event receivers. And only one redirect is `OK`. The 2nd one causes error you mention (because it tries to do 2nd redirect in single thread).

I deployed following sample you can use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace LongOperationlWebPart.EventReceiver1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        private static SortedDictionary<DateTime, Guid> transactions;
        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being deleted.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemDeleting(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            if (transactions == null) transactions = new SortedDictionary<DateTime, Guid>();
            Guid currentCorrelationId = CorrelationId.GetCurrentCorrelationToken();
            if (!transactions.ContainsValue(currentCorrelationId))
            {
                CleanIds(60);
                transactions.Add(DateTime.Now, currentCorrelationId);
                properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
                properties.RedirectUrl = "Default.aspx";
            }
            else base.ItemDeleting(properties);
        }

        private void CleanIds(double delay)
        {
            foreach (DateTime dt in transactions.Where(t => t.Key < DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1.0*delay)).Select(t => t.Key))
            {
                transactions.Remove(dt);
            }
        }

        public class CorrelationId
        {
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
            public static extern uint EventActivityIdControl(uint controlCode, ref  Guid activityId);
            public const uint EVENT_ACTIVITY_CTRL_GET_ID = 1;

            public static Guid GetCurrentCorrelationToken()
            {
                Guid g = Guid.Empty;
                EventActivityIdControl(EVENT_ACTIVITY_CTRL_GET_ID, ref  g);
                return g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```